# Kafka Failed authentication Unexpected handshake request with client mechanism PLAIN enabled mechanisms are []

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am getting below exception while trying to connect kafka in Ubuntu from Java Program in Windows

```
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Instantiated an idempotent producer.
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.AbstractLogin - Successfully logged in.
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka version: 3.5.0
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka commitId: c97b88d5db4de28d
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka startTimeMs: 1689709198762
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector -         
[Producer clientId=producer-1] Failed authentication with rakesh-virtual-machine/192.168.108.130 (channelId=-1) (Unexpected handshake request with client mechanism PLAIN, enabled mechanisms are [])
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - 
[Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 disconnected.
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] ERROR org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - 
[Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (rakesh-virtual-machine/x.x.x.x:9092) failed authentication due to: Unexpected handshake request with client mechanism PLAIN, enabled mechanisms are []
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient -         
[Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker rakesh-virtual-machine:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms.
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Metrics scheduler closed
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Closing reporter 
org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
```

My Java Cofig is

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "rakesh-virtual-machine:9092");
    properties.put("security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT");
    properties.put("sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN");
    properties.put("sasl.jaas.config", PlainLoginModule.class.getName()
            + " required username=\"admin\" password=\"12345\";");

    properties.setProperty("key.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getName());
    properties.setProperty("value.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getName());

    KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);
    ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>("test", "test_value");
    producer.send(record);
    producer.flush();
    producer.close();
```

Configuration of Kafka server.properties is below.

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092,CONTROLLER://0.0.0.0:9093
inter.broker.listener.name=PLAINTEXT
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://rakesh-virtual-machine:9092
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
listener.security.protocol.map=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your `listeners`/`advertised.listeners` are only enabling `PLAINTEXT` (so nothing). Therefore, error says `enabled mechanisms are []`.

Replace that with `SASL_PLAINTEXT`, as is defined in the mapping list, and ensure you've added the broker JAAS file as part of `KAFKA_OPTS` environment variable before running `kafka-server-start`